# How change dynamiclly the welcome-file in web.xml according to incoming ROOT request

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I want to display the index html in different   in 2 cases:

1. Recognise if the request come from Mobile device so redirect welcome-file to mobile.html ,
2. If the request come from web page redirect to second welcome-file web_index.html

   HOW CAN I DO A LOGIC , WHICH WELCOME FILE TO CHOOSE ??

   ```
       <welcome-file-list>
           <welcome-file>mobile.html</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>web_index.html</welcome-file>
   ```

P.S I'm using java ejb - Tomcat

My WEB.XML is the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">



    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Entire Application</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secured area</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>superuser</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>administration</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>administration area</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/admin.html</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>superuser</role-name>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>


    <security-role>
        <role-name>superuser</role-name>
    </security-role>



    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
            <path>/</path>
        </cookie-config>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>



    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Unsecured</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Unsecured area</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>LogoutFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.ngsoft.tt.ROOT.filters.LogoutFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LogoutFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>TitanLogin</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>welcome.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a bit of javascript.

Create a welcome page `index.html` with this content. It will redirect to `mobile.html` or `web_index.html` depending on the browser of client.

```
<script>
//from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/6371459
window.mobilecheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};

if (mobilecheck())
   window.location = "mobile.html";
else
   window.location = "web_index.html"; 

</script>
```

You can also set as home `web_index.html` or `mobile.html` and redirect to the other if the browser is not the correct one

Comment: Thanks , I'll check it , what about web.xml , how should I configure it  ?  and How set the welcome-file ???

Comment: Set a welcome file in the welcome-file-list of web.xml `<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>` The usual name is `index.html` but you can use the name you want